# GDB в VScode не останавливается на точках

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, makefile, gdb

Пишу аналог math.h библиотеки.
Для сборки проекта использую Makefile.
Буквально день назад проект дебажился через VScode и не было проблем. Сегодня, без каких-либо изменений, GDB проскакивает точки останова и программа просто отрабатывает, будто точек и не было.

Делал клонирование того коммита, где все работало, но на удивление - нет, дебаггер также стал проскакивать точки и на нем.

Пытался компилировать с `-g` флагом все файлы, пытался переустанавливать полностью VScode, переустанавливать расширения отдельно - не помогло.

Заранее спасибо за уделенное время, так как я в растерянности из-за этого.

Структура каталога:

```
| Folder/
|-----------| .vscode/
|-----------| src/
|-------------------| functions/
|----------------------------------| функции типа s21_cos.c, s21_sin.c ...
|-------------------| obj/
|-------------------| s21_math.c
|-------------------| s21_math.h
|-------------------| Makefile
```

Makefile:

```
OBJ_DIR = ./obj
FUN_DIR = ./functions

GCC_COMPILE = gcc -c -I ./ -Wall -Wextra -Werror
OBJECT_FILES = $(OBJ_DIR)/*.o s21_math.o
GOALS = s21_abs s21_acos s21_asin s21_atan s21_ceil s21_cos s21_fabs s21_fact s21_sin s21_math.o
GCC_BUILD = gcc -g $(OBJECT_FILES) s21_math.h -lm

s21_math: $(GOALS)
    rm -rf s21_math
    $(GCC_BUILD) -o s21_math

s21_abs:
    $(GCC_COMPILE) $(FUN_DIR)/$@.c -o $(OBJ_DIR)/$@.o

... (остальные функции собираются так-же)

s21_math.o:
    $(GCC_COMPILE) s21_math.c -o s21_math.o

clean:
    rm -rf *.txt
    rm -fr $(OBJ_DIR)/*.o s21_math s21_math.o
```

tasks.json:

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "Build",
            "command": "make --directory=src/",
            "group": "build"
        },
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

launch.json:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "(gdb) Launch",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/src/s21_math",
            "args": [
                "2"
            ],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                },
                {
                    "description": "Set Disassembly Flavor to Intel",
                    "text": "-gdb-set disassembly-flavor intel",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "Build"
        }
    ]
}
```

s21_math.c:

```
#include "s21_math.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

long double s21_tan(double x);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  clock_t start_time = clock();
  if (argc >= 2) {
    if (argv[1][0] == '1') {
      for (double a = -10; a < 10; a += 0.0001) {
        printf("Значение: %f\n", a);

        printf("%f\n", tan(a));

        printf("\n");
      }
    } else if (argv[1][0] == '2') {
      for (double a = -10; a < 10; a += 0.0001) {
        printf("Значение: %f\n", a);

        printf("%Lf\n", s21_tan(a));

        printf("\n");
      }
    }
  } else {
    // another test programm
  }

  start_time = clock() - start_time;
  printf("Время на работу программы: %ld", start_time);
  return 0;
}

long double s21_tan(double x) {
  x = fmod(x, S21_PI);
  long double cos_res = s21_cos(x);
  return !cos_res ? S21_NAN : s21_sin(x) / cos_res;
}
```

Comment: Я в CodeBlocks работаю, иногда ставлю точку останова на цикл. И останова нет. Но если поставить на строку выше, то срабатывает :)

Comment: @FrancNet, я сталкивался с таким, что "проскакивает", но у меня это случалось, если некорректно поставить саму точку. Например, на условие, до которого программа не доходит. Это не тот случай. 
Проверил на всякий случай, увы, нет.

Comment: Используйте IDE для С++, например Visual Studio или Eclipse. Файлы необходимо собирать с флагом `-g`, а лучше сразу с `-g3`, чего вы не делаете. Если gdb не работает в редакторе, то проверьте его работоспособность в консоли.

Comment: Ну по IDE могу с вами согласиться, что в них стоит писать программы. Все же их в целевую разрабатывали.
Однако сейчас это требование не работать в IDE.
Про флаг -g я писал, что использовал, но не работает.
А вот про -g3 и gdb в консоли попробую, спасибо.

Comment: @user7860670, спасибо за `-g3`, заработало. Правда, теперь работает и с обычным `-g` после применения `-g3`, но все же, спасибо)

Нужно будет почитать мануал на тему флага, чтобы разобраться в чем разница.

Comment: В приведенном в вопросе примере компилируется без `-g`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Необходимо использовать `-g3`, в случае, если не работает `-g`.